# Failure logging to file as JSON with logstash-logback-encoder

Tags: json, scala, logstash-logback-encoder

I've got a Scala application using [scala logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging) 3.5.0, [logback-classic](http://logback.qos.ch/) 1.1.7.  I am able to log to a plain text file without issue, but (although I'm not using logstash yet), I wanted to change the log file format to JSON using [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder).  My updated file appender definition now looks like this:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>logs/solomon.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
  <!-- daily rollover -->
  <fileNamePattern>solomon.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

  <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
  <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>

<encoder>
  <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
</encoder>
```

From the docs, it seems that this should log to the file as JSON, with all supported fields, but I'm getting an empty log file and the following error message on application startup:

```
09:05:58,101 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:05:58,102 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@24:70 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][encoder]]
09:05:58,102 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout("null") - Empty or null pattern.
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious; my setup seems very similar to others I've seen (which simply want JSON file logging, but which aren't yet using logstash).  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my fault...I had nested encoder declarations.  Once I removed that, everything worked fine.  I guess I posted too soon!

Comment: So, as an answer, could you share your correct configuration file.